# Communication between angular 2 and pure javascript

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am building an angular application and i am in a situation where i have to communicate with an external javascript.

**Scenario**
During app initialization, i inject two iframes into index.html using

```
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

I have script running in index.html and has a multiple functions among which one is getData();  I have to send data to this function from the angular app component when the app initialises. How to go about this ? I know how to communicate from javascript to angular but not the other way round. Please help me. I am struck.

Comment: A callback function is exposed on `window` by Angular app and is called by non-Angular app. A callback function is exposed on `window` by non-Angular app and is called by Angular app. That's two-way communication.

Comment: can you post some small example or direct me to proper resource ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic communication can be performed via callbacks.

A callback can be defined either by Angular or non-Angular application. depending on the direction of communication.

```
@Injectable()
class GlobalService {
  constructor() {
    window.vanillaToAngularCallback = data => {
      // communicate with other Angular providers
    }
  }
}
```

And/or

```
window.angularToVanillaCallback = data => {
  // communicate with other vanilla JS code
}
```

Where `angularToVanillaCallback` is supposed to be called inside Angular, and `vanillaToAngularCallback` is called outside Angular. The time of first callback calls should be chosen correctly; callbacks shouldn't be called by one side until they will be defined by another side.

It's still preferable to keep non-Angular part as a Webpack bundle. This way the reference to `window` can be avoided, and common classes can be used for communication with Angular part, either via callbacks or RxJS subjects.

Comment: How do you call the function from Angular? `window.angularToVanillaCallback();` throws an error

Comment: Ok, `window['angularToVanillaCallback']();` works